# How to add to a 2D list of Object class

Tags: java, swing

I'm creating a table from JFC Swing which takes in parameters (Object[][], Object[]) which represent rowData and columnNames. I want to iterate through each student to get values of each of their fields, but for some reason my rowData keeps pointing to null. I checked and the value gets printed succesfully, but it doesn't get placed in my 2D object list. Here's the part that causes an error:

```
        AddEntity ae= new AddEntity();
        ae.addStudent(s);
        ArrayList<Student> students=ae.getStudenti();
        
        int i=0;
        Object[][] rowData=null;
        for (Student sIt: students) {
            
            Object[] studentData = sIt.getData();
            int j=0;
            for (Object sIt2:studentData) {
                **rowData[i][j]=sIt2;**
                j++;
                System.out.printf("%d %s\n", j,sIt2);
            }
            i++;
        }
```

Stacktrace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot load from object array because "rowData" is null
    at Table.ShowTable.showStudent(ShowTable.java:37)
    at gui.MyApp.main(MyApp.java:34)
```

EDIT: changed it to ArrayList<ArrayList>, but can't convert it back to Object[][] at the end:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>> temp=new ArrayList<ArrayList<Object>>();
        for (Student sIt: students) {
            ArrayList<Object> data=new ArrayList<Object>();
            Object[] studentData = sIt.getData();
            int j=0;
            for (Object sIt2:studentData) {
                data.add(sIt2);
                j++;
                System.out.printf("%d %s\n", j,sIt2);
            }
            temp.add(data);
            i++;
        }

   Object[][] rowData=temp; //Line that doesn't work
```

EDIT2: For clarification, length is known at the end of the loop but width is different for each row, and doing temp.toArray(new Object[][]) requires dimensions, so i have no idea how to cast it

Comment: `Object[][] rowData=null;`?  When is `rowData` initialised?

Comment: Yeah that line is definitely wrong, but it won't let me do Object[][] rowData= new Object[][] (Variable must provide either dimension expressions or an array initializer). However I don't know the size of it beforehand, and the solution is probably to use ArrayList, but I need it to be Object[][] at the end

Comment: The update with the arraylist is good, now you just need to correctly create the array `Object[][] rowData= new Object[x][y];`, then you can iterate over the ArrayList at the end with two for loops and assign the values to the `Object[][]` Array. The values `x` and `y` are known and you can get these from your temp ArrayList using the length and the largest row `Object[][] rowData= new Object[temp.size()][largestRowSize];`

Comment: Don't forget to check for `null` values when working with values from the completed `rowData` array, because you don't want to run into any NullPointerExceptions.